# React: On click update a child component from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to show a table of data on click on a number in another component called Sidebar. I have a parent component ShowTable and two child components Sidebar and Table. However, because I have componentDidMount in Table it only shows the table for the first click. On the second click the table doesn't change, since it has already been mounted. Does anyone know how I could solve this, so that on every click the table would reload? So, how could I trigger a function in the child from the parent component or what could I use instead of componentDidMount? I tried using componentDidUpdate, so that every time a new serial is sent by props the component would load again, however, it starts to infinately loop.

Function handleSelect in ShowTable:

```
handleSelect=(value)=>{
    this.setState( {serial: value, showComponent: true} )
    console.log(this.state.serial)
}
```

In render ShowTable:

```
{this.state.showComponent ?
<Table s={this.state.serial}/>:
null 
}
```

In Sidebar:

```
{this.props.se.map((number) => ( 
                <li>
                        <a onClick={()=>this.props.handleSelect(number.ta)}>{number.ta}</a>
                    </li>
                    ))};
```

In Table:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    
        const database = db.ref().child("Devices/" + this.props.s);
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think this is about parents and children and stuff, this is only about  writing correct code inside `componentDidUpdate` and thereby preventing an infinite loop. Please post your previous attempt at this, the one that caused the loop. It's probably as simple as `if (this.props.s != prevProps.s) ...`

Comment: If you want to "remount" the component, this is the way.
https://codesandbox.io/s/conditional-rendering-jj218
"clicked" works just like your "showComponent"

Comment: Thanks for both of your answers! By properly using componentDidUpdate I managed to solve the issue.